# Perform multiple callout inside batch process

Tags: apex, api, integration, callout, governorlimits

Good day everyone. I am trying to sync my salesforce data and xero data. I want to get all xero contacts and save it to salesforce accounts. What I did is that I query the xero data by page. The problem I have at the moment is that I encounter this error. `Too many callouts: 1` . I dont know what I am doing wrong but here is some part of my code.

```
public with sharing class BatchSyncXeroToSalesforce implements Database.batchable<XeroContact>, Database.Stateful 
{ 

  public List<XeroContact> res = new List<XeroContact>();
    public Integer PAGE {get;set;}

    public BatchSyncXeroToSalesforce(Integer thePage) {
        PAGE = thePage;
    }

  public Iterable<XeroContact> start(Database.batchableContext batchableContext) { 
        // the below code is the callout to xero where I use the page number as parameter
        res = XeroAccountingApi.getContactByPage(PAGE);
        return res;
  }

  public void execute(Database.BatchableContext batchableContext, List<XeroContact> scope)  {
    // this is where I process the data from xero
  }

  public void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc) {

    //system.debug('mJobId : '+jobID);
    if(res.size() > 0) {
      Integer x = PAGE+1;
      BatchSyncXeroToSalesforce b = new BatchSyncXeroToSalesforce(x); 
      database.executebatch(b,1);   
    }

  }

}
```

Please help ... thank you...

Answer (score 0):

please add "Database.allowscallouts" on Interface.

public with sharing class BatchSyncXeroToSalesforce implements Database.batchable 
< XeroContact >, Database.Stateful,Database.allowscallouts
{

}